# Why calls std::any the destructor twice?

Tags: c++

Out of curiosity: I worked with type erasure in my code base and then I noticed that the destructor of an object is called twice.

I simplified it with std::any and even with std::any the destructor is called twice:

https://godbolt.org/z/jaEqq7Psa

```
struct foo 
{
    foo() {std::cout << "ctor\n"; }
    ~foo() {std::cout << "dtor\n"; }
};

int main() 
{    
    std::any any_foo = foo{}; 
    return 0;
}
```

I did the same example already considering the rule of 5 and there is a move constructor once called, I played around, but I couldn't eliminate the multiple destructor calls.

Comment: `foo{}` is a temporary object, it needs destructing. If you want to eliminate it, use `emplace`.

Comment: "I did the same example already considering the rule of 5 and there is a move constructor once called, I played around, but I couldn't eliminate the multiple destructor calls." Did you try to check when/where that move constructor is called, along with assignment operator and copy constructor?

Comment: The destructor is not called twice for the same object. But if you are coping an object (or move it), then both are destroyed. Try instrumenting your copy constructor and move constructor - also Copy assignment and move assignment operators.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, it already helped me. thanks you all

Comment: *Why calls std::any the destructor twice?* -- Next time, print the value of `this`, not just "dtor".  [You would then see that the object being destroyed is not the same.](https://godbolt.org/z/7eYcWonKq)

Comment: *I noticed that the destructor of an object is called twice.*  No, it's two separate objects.  Each object needs to be destructed.  The compiler synthesizes constructors for the other constructors (copy constructor, move constructor) that you did not provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> there is a move constructor once called

This should be a honking clue that you have more than one object that you're working with.

Every constructed object gets destroyed, at some point, in well-formed and well-defined code. This is fundamental to C++.

A move constructor does not change this rule. The move constructor is, itself, a constructor. So it constructs one object. But the moved-from object also, at some point, must have been constructed. So now there are at least two objects that will, at some point, get destroyed. The moved-from object is still a C++ object that was constructed, at some point. So it must get destroyed, at some point. This is true even if, at some point, its was moved-from. All that a move operation does is leave the moved-from object in some "valid, but unspecified" state. It is still a valid object. It'll get destroyed.

```
std::any any_foo = foo{};
```

First, a temporary `foo` object gets created. Then `std::any` gets constructed and it swallows up this `foo`. However `std::any` can't just absorb some other object by osmosis, somehow. The only thing that a `std::any` can do is copy/move construct another `foo` that it owns. This is where you see the move constructor getting invoked.

Finally, the temporary `foo` gets destroyed. And, later, `std::any` gets destroyed and its destructor then also destroys the `foo` that it owns. That's your second destructor call.

It is fundamental, here, that `std::any` has its own object, whatever object it is, that it owns. It cannot take over ownership of another object that was constructed already.

Comment: Plus one for _"can't just absorb some other object by osmosis"_. Could someone please request that an osmosis constructor is included in c++26? ;)

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade sure, feel free to submit such a proposal yourself ;-)

Comment: Isn't *osmosis constructor* the same as *destructive move*?